# Groupby with counts + aggregate row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code which produces a data frame showing me a per month and per year average sold price. I would like to add to this a total row per year and a total row per `pid` (person). Sample code and data:

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO

s = StringIO.StringIO("""pid,year,month,price
    1,2017,4,2000
    1,2017,4,2900
    1,2018,4,2000
    1,2018,4,2300
    1,2018,5,2000
    1,2018,5,1990
    1,2018,6,2200
    1,2018,6,2400
    1,2018,6,2250
    1,2018,7,2150
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(s)
maths = {'price': 'mean'}
gb = df.groupby(['pid','year','month'])
counts = gb.size().to_frame(name='n')
out = counts.join(gb.agg(maths)).reset_index()
print(out)
```

Which yields:

```
   pid  year  month  n        price
0    1  2017      4  2  2450.000000
1    1  2018      4  2  2150.000000
2    1  2018      5  2  1995.000000
3    1  2018      6  3  2283.333333
4    1  2018      7  1  2150.000000
```

I would the additional per year rows to look like:

```
   pid  year  month  n        price
0    1  2017    all  2  2450.000000
0    1  2018    all  8  2161.000000
```

And then the per `pid` rollup to look like:

```
   pid  year  month  n        price
0    1  all     all  10  2218.000000
```

I'm having trouble cleanly grouping/aggregating those last two frames where I essentially want an `all` split for each `year` and `month` value, and then have each data frame here combined into one which I can write to CSV, or a database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.concat`

```
df1=df.groupby(['pid','year','month']).price.agg(['size','mean']).reset_index()
df2=df.groupby(['pid','year']).price.agg(['size','mean']).assign(month='all').reset_index()
df3=df.groupby(['pid']).price.agg(['size','mean']).assign(**{'month':'all','year':'all'}).reset_index()
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
Out[484]: 
          mean month  pid  size  year
0  2450.000000     4    1     2  2017
1  2150.000000     4    1     2  2018
2  1995.000000     5    1     2  2018
3  2283.333333     6    1     3  2018
4  2150.000000     7    1     1  2018
0  2450.000000   all    1     2  2017
1  2161.250000   all    1     8  2018
0  2219.000000   all    1    10   all
```

Comment: there is no `n` in the original `df` though, so adding that to the `agg` dict is bombing.

Comment: @Wells df is from `df= counts.join(gb.agg(maths)).reset_index()`

Comment: right, though, aren't we then averaging the averages as `counts` joined the `gb.agg()` call?